# Replacing System.Drawing with ImageSharp for Barcode .net core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0, zxing.net, imagesharp

As we have upgraded to net core 6 we are rewriting some of our code base. We have a tag helper in AspNet Core which generates a barcode.  This currently uses System.Drawing and ZXing.

TagHelper Old version using System.Drawing - working (top barcode)

```cs
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var margin = 0;
    var qrCodeWriter = new ZXing.BarcodeWriterPixelData
    {
        Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.PDF_417,
        Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
        {
            Height = this.Height > 80 ? this.Height : 80,
            Width = this.Width > 400 ? this.Width : 400,
            Margin = margin
        }
    };
    var pixelData = qrCodeWriter.Write(QRCodeContent);
    // creating a bitmap from the raw pixel data; if only black and white colors are used it makes no difference
    // that the pixel data ist BGRA oriented and the bitmap is initialized with RGB
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height),
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        try
        {
            // we assume that the row stride of the bitmap is aligned to 4 byte multiplied by the width of the image
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0,
            pixelData.Pixels.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }
        // save to stream as PNG
        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        output.TagName = "img";
        output.Attributes.Clear();
        output.Attributes.Add("width", Width);
        output.Attributes.Add("height", Height);
        output.Attributes.Add("alt", Alt);
        output.Attributes.Add("src",
        $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())}");
    }
}
```

TagHelper new version using ImageSharp - almost working but not exactly (bottom barcode)

```cs
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var margin = 0;
    var barcodeWriter = new ZXing.ImageSharp.BarcodeWriter<SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.La32>
    {
        Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.PDF_417,
        Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
        {
            Height = this.Height > 80 ? this.Height : 80,
            Width = this.Width > 400 ? this.Width : 400,
            Margin = margin
        }
    };

    var image = barcodeWriter.Write(QRCodeContent);
    output.TagName = "img";
    output.Attributes.Clear();
    output.Attributes.Add("width", Width);
    output.Attributes.Add("height", Height);
    output.Attributes.Add("alt", Alt);
    output.Attributes.Add("src", $"{image.ToBase64String(PngFormat.Instance)}");
}
```

The issue is as mentioned the 2nd barcode is very slightly different at the end seems to extend the last bar.

What am I missing?

[image: Results]

Comment: Is the second barcode actually wrong, though?

Comment: In terms of the display yes. Scanner has issue. So I'm told as it's client app and only they can test it.

Comment: After my test, just `PDF_417` has this issue, and I also try to use `0.16.10`, and the result is also different, maybe you can create a isuue on github.

Comment: @Jason Yeah was thinking of doing just that will create an issue with SixLabs.

Comment: Odd they said its probably a ZXing issue.

Comment: `ZXing.ImageSharp.BarcodeWriter` is code in the XZing.Net repo which is the library your dealing with to create the image. As they are the ones responsible for creating the image instance and populating it with pixel data then they will be the people you want to raise the issue with... as also hinted by the fact its only an issue with one of their barcode types.

Comment: also please make sure your disposing of that `Image` you are getting out of the barcode writer otherwise your going to have a sad time with regards your processes memory.

Comment: https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Source/Bindings/ZXing.ImageSharp/BarcodeWriter.cs for the class in the ZXing repo that you are calling.

Comment: @tocsoft Appreciate it will follow it up with them.

Answer (score 2):

That is a bug in the renderer implementation of the ZXing.Net binding to ImageSharp.
https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/issues/422
It is fixed in the newest nuget package of the bindings.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.ImageSharp/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.ImageSharp.V2/